# Underlining in DIA

Tags: sql, diagram, dia

Just started working on E-R diagrams for the first time and I can't seem to be able to underline. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Underline 'hh' or 'licence number' for example

Comment: Didn't see anything in the manual, and there are some forum posts that suggest it doesn't exist (though to be fair, those posts are a few years old).  Suggest you contact the project.

Answer (score 11):

as you are not creating a flowchart, but an er, you should change your palette :) click on the left side of your screen where it says "flowchart", and select "er". now use the tool "attribute" from this new palette. check out the properties of this one! no underlining..... but!! primary key :D dia is even semantically correct.

you should use the tools from this palette exclusively when creating er diagrams. so use "entity" for that box in your screenshot that says "person".

draw lines between entities and relations with the line tool from the er palette, use the generic line tool from the basic tools on your top left for the attributes. and make sure everything is connected via their handles (displayed on each object as tiny tiny x:es). makes it easier to move things around :)

good luck!